# How could I prevent stayontop property of opendialog in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a small application which contains a self created popupmenu. When I want to use opendialog, popupmenu doesn't work because opendialog has stayontop feature by default.

Comment: TOpenDialog isn't stay-on-top. Do you mean modal?

Comment: yes, modal not stayontop.

Comment: The user cannot click on anything except the `TOpenDialog` window while it is open.  Are you trying to display a PopupMenu programmably?  Why?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: File dialogs are modal. Nothing much you can do about that. Why is a modal dialog a problem to you?

Comment: My menu is disappears when menu is not focused. when opendialog shows, it is modal and prevents showing menu by take away the focus from menu but I will use some tricks If I run out of ideas.

Comment: That's how these components are meant to work

Comment: Ok, that's no problem, I just wanted to know which possibilities I have but it will recoded another way. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want the popup menu to remain visible?  It seems to me that once the user has selected an item the menu would be finished with until the user wishes to perform another action.

Comment: If you want to still show the user what he selected from the menu then why not just add that menu item's caption to the OpenDialog's caption to show the user.